# How to create a custom slider view in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am looking at creating a custom slider, with a gradient background, numbers to represent the values, and white dots on the line to show where each step is, what I'm looking for looks like this:

[image: Slider Image]

I have looked at several other tutorials but none of what I do gives me the result Im after, either because elements don't line up, or my code doesn't work as well as the default slider.

An extra bit of trickiness is I also want to have the snap to position like the default slider, so a user can't select a value of 6.5522, only 6 or seven.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomSlider: View {
let textColor: Color
let thumbColor: Color
let height: CGFloat
let cornerRadius: CGFloat

@State var lastOffset: CGFloat = 0

@Binding var value: CGFloat

var range: ClosedRange<CGFloat>

var leadingOffset: CGFloat = 5
var trailingOffset: CGFloat = 5



var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius).fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.paleRed, .mango, .neonYellow, .midGreen]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                    .frame(height: height)
                HStack {
                    ForEach(1..<11) { index in
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: height, height: height)
                        if index < 10 {
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
                HStack {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: height * 2, height: height * 2)
                        .foregroundColor(thumbColor)
                        .offset(x: CGFloat(self.$value.wrappedValue.map(from: self.range, to: 6...(geo.size.width - 6 - 22))))
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                                .onChanged { value in

                                    if abs(value.translation.width) < 0.1 {
                                        self.lastOffset = self.$value.wrappedValue.map(from: self.range, to: self.leadingOffset...(geo.size.width - (height * 2) - self.trailingOffset))
                                    }

                                    let sliderPos = max(0 + self.leadingOffset, min(self.lastOffset + value.translation.width, geo.size.width - (height * 2) - self.trailingOffset))
                                    let sliderVal = sliderPos.map(from: self.leadingOffset...(geo.size.width - (height * 2) - self.trailingOffset), to: self.range)

                                    self.value = sliderVal
                                }
                      )
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            HStack {
                ForEach(1..<11) { index in
                    Text("\(index)")
                        .foregroundColor(.secondaryButtonLightGrey)
                        .font(.custom("Rubik-Medium", size: 16))
                    if index < 10 {
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
}
```

// How its implemented in the view code:

```
CustomSlider(textColor: .textColor, thumbColor: .thumbColor, height: 10, cornerRadius: 10, value: $value, range: 0...10)
```

I apologize if these are really simple questions but I am still new to swiftUI, only been using it for a month.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this may help:

```
    struct CustomSliderView: View {
    @State var slider: Float = 0
    @State var dragGestureTranslation: CGFloat = 0
    @State var lastDragValue: CGFloat = 0
    
    // Slider Draggable Control Settings
    var sliderWidth: CGFloat = 30
    var sliderPadding: CGFloat = 0 // This adds padding to each side
    
    // Stepped Increment
    @State var steppedSlider: Bool = false
    @State var step: Int = 8
    @State var stepInterval: CGFloat = 0
    
    func interval(width: CGFloat, increment: Int) -> CGFloat {
        print("Screen Width: \(width)")
        let result = width * CGFloat(increment) / CGFloat(step)
        return result
    }
    
    func roundToFactor(value: CGFloat, factor: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return factor * round(value / factor)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                // Slider Bar
                ZStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                } // End of Slider Bar
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 3)
                .padding(.vertical, 15) // Padding to centre the bar
                
                // Slider Stacker
                ZStack (alignment: .top) {
                    if steppedSlider {
                        // Step - Minused the SliderWidth so that it is evenly spaced
                        ForEach(0...step, id: \.self) { number in
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 2, height: 10)
                                .offset(x: interval(width: (geometry.size.width - sliderWidth), increment: number), y: 46)
                            
                            Text("\(number)")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .offset(x: interval(width: (geometry.size.width - sliderWidth), increment: number), y: 64)
                                
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // Draggable Slider
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: sliderWidth, height: 30)
                    }
                    .offset(x: CGFloat(slider))
                    .padding(.horizontal, sliderPadding)
                } // End of Slider ZStack
                .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                            .onChanged({ dragValue in
                                let translation = dragValue.translation
                                
                                dragGestureTranslation = CGFloat(translation.width) + lastDragValue
                                
                                // Set the start marker of the slider
                                dragGestureTranslation = dragGestureTranslation >= 0 ? dragGestureTranslation : 0
                                
                                // Set the end marker of the slider
                                dragGestureTranslation = dragGestureTranslation > (geometry.size.width - sliderWidth - sliderPadding * 2) ? (geometry.size.width - sliderWidth - sliderPadding * 2) :  dragGestureTranslation
                                
                                // Set the slider value (Stepped)
                                if steppedSlider {
                                    // Getting the stepper interval (where to place the marks)
                                    stepInterval = roundToFactor(value: dragGestureTranslation, factor: (geometry.size.width - sliderWidth - (sliderPadding * 2)) / CGFloat(step))
                                    
                                    // Get the increments for the stepepdInterval
                                    self.slider = min(max(0, Float(stepInterval)), Float(stepInterval))
                                } else {
                                    // Set the slider value (Fluid)
                                    self.slider = min(max(0, Float(dragGestureTranslation)), Float(dragGestureTranslation))
                                }

                            })
                            .onEnded({ dragValue in
                                // Set the start marker of the slider
                                dragGestureTranslation = dragGestureTranslation >= 0 ? dragGestureTranslation : 0
                                
                                // Set the end marker of the slider
                                dragGestureTranslation = dragGestureTranslation > (geometry.size.width - sliderWidth - sliderPadding * 2) ? (geometry.size.width - sliderWidth - sliderPadding * 2) : dragGestureTranslation
                                
                                // Storing last drag value
                                lastDragValue = dragGestureTranslation
                            })
                ) // End of DragGesture
            } // End of GeometryReader
            Text("Slider: \(slider)")
        } // End of VStack
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can answer to the second part of your question.
To get the Integer value, you just have to cast the value.
For example:

```
self.value = Int(sliderVal)
```